# Cant scroll to new item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, paging, coroutine

I just want recycler view to scroll to last position when receiving message from StompClient. I am using StompClient library. And when i am getting new message i am updating RV Adapter, but i cant scroll it for some reason.
I've tried postdelaying it but it worked only in OnClickListener, not in coroutine, in coroutine i am trying with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` but it is not working as well.

[image]

Comment: Your scroll position is `0` which is always the first item, you can pass the item of the last index which can be retrieved from the adapter as `chatAdapter.itemCount - 1`.

Comment: @DarShan Oh, sry my bad, i meant last received, so i need index 0, but the problem is that it is not working in coroutineScope, even with withContext

Comment: Try moving the `binding.messagesRv.scrollToPosition(0)` inside the `collectLatest` block as thats when the scroll should happen, also, `withContext` is not required.

Comment: @DarShan Nope, that's not working, because we cant update UI on Dispatchers.IO

Comment: @tobi1805 Nope, same result

Comment: `collectLatest` suspends the coroutine until completion, so the next statement won't be executed (I'm assuming `getChatMessages()` returns a Flow that doesn't complete). In any case, if you want to scroll when you receive messages you probably should move the `scrollToPosition` inside the lambda after you call `submitData`. I'm not sure the adapter will be already refreshed at that time though.

Comment: Btw, if you're using a well built (i.e. [main safe](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#use-coroutines-for-main-safety)) library for getting your data (e.g. Room, Retrofit), you don't need `Dispatchers.IO`.